# openshift deployment failing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift

my openshift deployment of rails 3.2 app fails , just after it tries to precompile assets

```
remote: Deployment id is 7aea3738
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Precompiling with 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile'
remote: /opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/bin/ruby /var/lib/openshift/52e891c24382ec693c000092/app-      root/runtime/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/
bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
remote: rake aborted!
remote: Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is   not part of the bundle. Add it to
Gemfile.)
```

this is my gemfile

```
source 'http://mirror1.prod.rhcloud.com/mirror/ruby/'
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.14'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'rack-cache', :require => 'rack/cache'
gem 'dragonfly', '~>0.9.15'
gem 'minitest'
gem 'thor', '= 0.14.6'
gem 'sqlite3','1.3.5'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
group :development,:test do
gem 'sqlite3','1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails','2.11.0'
end 

group :development do
gem 'annotate','2.5.0'
end



# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier','1.2.3'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby


end

gem 'jquery-rails','2.0.2'

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
gem 'sqlite3','1.3.5'

end


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

the code works perefectly on my windows 8 development environment, i want to use persistent storage and sqlite ( i got a similar error when trying  mysql also , which is why i shifted to sqlite)

Comment: Did you run "bundle install" on your localhost before pushing your code

Comment: yes i did run bundle install

Comment: And are both your Gemfile and your Gemfile.lock checked in to your repo?

Comment: yes both the gemfile and gemfile.lock are commited